# Razor Layout doesn't work if file is called _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an MVC3 web app to which I want to start using whole Razor views.

Most of the site is working fine with a Site.Master so I've packaged up most of it into partial views and am trying to add a layout with the same content.

After reading Scott Gu's blog I've added a file called _ViewStart.cshtml in my `~/Views` directory so that it'll be applied by default.

Unfortunately this gives me the error:

`The name 'RenderBody' does not exist in the current context`

If the file is called `_viewstart.cshtml`.

If it is called `_layoutviewstart.cshtml` it will work but I have to reference it directly in the view.

If it's called `_billyviewstart.cshtml` is works but again I have to reference it directly in the view.

Comment: Site.Master? Are you just trying to convert an existing site? There's probably configuration changes required that you don't have.

Comment: hello, we use view start to defined default layout, defined default layout will be stay in shared folder. of course it must have @RenderBody().

Answer (score 13, accepted):

View start

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
     @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no! be sure you are not. :) we always wonder that renderbody when we start MVC3 after ASP.NET master page.

Comment: its _Layout.cshtml in link, so update file name from Layout.cshtml to _Layout.cshtml

Comment: @baqer_naqvi answer was 4 years ago but not difference  with _ (underscore) or without it. it was useful name convention for shared cshtml.

Comment: No offense! I'am just a beginner :) @NuriYILMAZ

Answer (score 4):

This error will be raised when you include `@RenderBody` directive on a page with `@page` directive at the top. By adding `@page` you have directed ASP.Net Core that it is a page and not layout. Therefore, the compiler does not expect `RenderBody` to be included on the page.

To fix this error, remove `@page` directive from layout.