# RenderBody in _viewstart not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Newbie question:

From resources I've found on google it looks like I ought to be able to put @RenderBody() in my _viewstart.cshtml file, but I get an error when I try saying that it doesn't exist.

How can I specify in my viewstart where I want my view to be rendered?

Comment: what doesn't exist? Can you add full exception/error and your viewstart.cshtml please? RenderBody() is what you need to use to render the body, if we can see your error and file we can identify the problem.

Comment: @vgSefa I'll post a screenshot when I get back but the error is saying that RenderBody() doesn't exist.

Comment: Looks like this guy might have had the same issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025057/razor-layout-doesnt-work-if-file-is-called-viewstart-cshtml