# The name viewbag does not exist in the current context mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello I am using visual studio professional 2015 and I created  a mvc 5 project, but I am having 3 errors:

- the name 'viewbag' does not exist in the current context
- the name 'Renderbody'does not exist in the current context
- the name 'RenderSection' does not exist in the current context

I am using mvc 5, I searched online and found many solutions but they are not for my case.

This is the \Views\Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <add namespace="TLN" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is the \Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

and This is the _ViewStart.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Contoso University</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Contoso University", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Students", "Index", "Student")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Courses", "Index", "Course")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Instructors", "Index", "Instructor")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Departments", "Index", "Department")</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Contoso University</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone knows what is the error in this case?

Comment: If you build the MVC project, do you still have the errors?

Comment: yes I tried cleaning building rebuilding the project and the errors remained

Comment: I think that @NightOwl888 was wondering if the page was rendered correctly when you run it, or if you have exceptions at runtime.

Comment: yes when running the error appears in the browser with the location of the first error @ViewBag.Title   in /_ViewStart.cshtml

Comment: _ViewStart.cshtml usually contains layout for all views. Can you separate the layout HTML markup on layout files and refer them on _ViewStart? Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025057/razor-layout-doesnt-work-if-file-is-called-viewstart-cshtml

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to fixing all the errors related to intelligent in the view (Razor MVC)

I had this issue regardless of having all the correct configuration done in the web.config file.

When i open the .cshtml file and build i was getting number of errors.

Found out to be ***some bad files in the Component Cache, preventing the Razor views from recognising ViewBag, Model, and HtmlHelpers. Deleting these files solved the problem*** (good versions of these files were created next time I opened Visual Studio).

**Please follow below path to discover the files:**

```
C:\Users\your.name.here\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

**Delete all four files:**

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.catalogs
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.err
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.external

I closed my project, deleted the files on that path and reopened my project, cleaned the solution and built it again and the problem was solved

Deleting your Temporary ASP.NET Files also helps. C:\Users\your.name.here\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files.

This works for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the `_ViewStart.cshtml` file should contain your .cshtml layout file refers to markup of all .cshtml views.

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
   @* this method below should be exist in your body tag *@
   @RenderBody()

   @RenderSection(...)
</body>
</html>
```

Afterwards, you can have `ViewBag.Title` on view pages that use your custom layout above:

View.cshtml

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Page Title";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```